# Search is not working by product attributes

Tags: magento2.3, forms, search

We have added couple of products on our Magento 2 site. In the home page of the site, we have a search form and there we have put input boxes as product name, from, to and location. We want to display the results as per the selected criteria in the form but its not working as expected.

Code:

```
<dd id="construction" class="item content active" data-role="content" >

                    <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('catalogsearch/result/');?>">
                        <fieldset class="search-forms-fieldset" id="date-range-1">
                        <legend class="legend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Search Settings') ?></span></legend>

                        <div class="field region">
                            <label for="select" class="label"><span>Select</span></label>

                            <div class="control" id="conselect">
                                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('What are you looking for?') ?>" />
                                <?php /*?><select name="looking" id="looking">
                                    <option value="">Please select</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                </select><?php */?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="location" class="label"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Location') ?></span></label>

                            <div class="control" id="conlocation">
                                <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Location') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="available_from" class="label"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Available From') ?></span></label>

                            <div class="control" id="confrom">
                                <input type="text" name="available_from" placeholder="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Available From') ?>" id="date-from-1" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="available_to" class="label"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Location') ?></span></label>

                            <div class="control" id="conto">
                                <input type="text" name="available_to" placeholder="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Available To') ?>" id="date-to-1"/>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="actions-toolbar">
                          <div class="primary">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="action search primary"
                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Search') ?></span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>  
                    </form>

                </dd>
```

Please see the below screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Comment: please check in **stores -> attributes -> product** on your attribute row `searchable` or `use in search` column is set to `yes`

Comment: @MohitRane, I have checked and see the attribute is searchable

Comment: @MohitRane, What others should I check?

Comment: it should be working fine if it's searchable

Comment: @MohitRane, Yes it should work but in my case it's not working as expected. I have posted the code. Can you check it and let me know where am i wrong?

Comment: @Siva Did you do reindexing? if not then do it first and check

Comment: @SavanPatel, I have did that as well but not working. Can you check my code, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Elasticsearch, make sure there is a successful connection and your indexers are valid.

**Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search > Search Engine**

Make sure the products are **in stock** with quantity of 1 or greater, and visibility is Catalog, Search

Since this is custom code, verify that the extension is enabled. Sometimes running `bin/magento cache:clean` makes a difference.